# ShellExecute not working or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, shellexecute

So, shortly, I need to launch a program with launch options, in my case - Steam.
In the beginnings of my little program I've used system() to launch it, now I want to launch it with `ShellExecute()`, but it does nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define STEAM_DIRECTORY "D:\\Programs\\Steam\\steam.exe"

int main()
{
    ....
    string arguments = "- login " + login[num - 1] + " " + pass[num - 1];
    ShellExecute(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"open", (LPCWSTR)STEAM_DIRECTORY, (LPCWSTR)arguments.c_str(), NULL, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
}
```

What I've used before:

```
#define STEAM_DIRECTORY "\"D:\\Programs\\Steam\\steam.exe\""

int main()
{
    ....
    string runsteam_arg = STEAM_DIRECTORY;
    runsteam_arg = runsteam_arg + " -login " + login[num - 1] + " " + pass[num - 1];
    system(runsteam_arg.c_str());
}
```

Edit: What I need to run in the end:

```
"D:\Programs\Steam\steam.exe" -login xxxx xxxx
```

And one more thing, can somebody explain what `CoInitializeEx()` does? I'm new to Windows API.

Comment: Those (LPCWSTR) casts only stopped the compiler from telling you that you were doing it wrong, it did not stop you from doing it wrong.  Prefix L to create a Unicode literal, like L"open".  Or use ShellExecuteA().  And do not ignore the return value of a winapi function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type casting the pointers with `(LPCWSTR)` is not sufficient, you need to convert the string from ANSI to Unicode.

The simplest (but not the best) solution for you would be to call `ShellExecuteA` instead.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define STEAM_DIRECTORY "D:\\Programs\\Steam\\steam.exe"

int main()
{
    ....
    string arguments = "- login " + login[num - 1] + " " + pass[num - 1];
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", STEAM_DIRECTORY, arguments.c_str(), NULL, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
}
```

Getting real Unicode strings would require you to write `L"str"` instead of `"str"`. And you would need to use `wstring` instead of `string`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define STEAM_DIRECTORY L"D:\\Programs\\Steam\\steam.exe"

int main()
{
    ....
    wstring arguments = L"- login " + login[num - 1] + L" " + pass[num - 1];
    ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", STEAM_DIRECTORY, arguments.c_str(), NULL, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
}
```

Also: don't forget to `CoInitialize()` before using `ShellExecute(Ex)`, for example with:

```
const HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
```

Comment: Updated main post.

Comment: CoInitializeEx initializes COM (the Component Object Model system).  Some parts of Windows, like Shell, use COM and therefore depend on it being initialized.

Comment: This is clearly stated in the `ShellExecute()` documentation: "*Because ShellExecute can delegate execution to Shell extensions (data sources, context menu handlers, verb implementations) that are activated using Component Object Model (COM), COM should be initialized before ShellExecute is called ... There are certainly instances where ShellExecute does not use one of these types of Shell extension and those instances would not require COM to be initialized at all. Nonetheless, it is good practice to always initalize COM before using this function.*"